# Rewriting HTML code using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some markup here that I need to reformat using javascript. Basically, I have this code:

```
    <div id="images">    
      <img src="01.jpg">
      <img src="02.jpg">
      <img src="03.jpg">
      <img src="04.jpg">
      <a id="src" href="01.jpg"></a>
      <a id="src" href="02.jpg"></a>
      <a id="src" href="03.jpg"></a>
      <a id="src" href="04.jpg"></a>
    </div>
```

and I want javascript to rewrite the code so that the images are placed inside the anchors. Like this:

```
    <div id="images">    
      <a id="src" href="01.jpg"><img src="01.jpg"></a>
      <a id="src" href="02.jpg"><img src="02.jpg"></a>
      <a id="src" href="03.jpg"><img src="03.jpg"></a>
      <a id="src" href="04.jpg"><img src="04.jpg"></a>
    </div>
```

any ideas?

Comment: By the way, you can't have `id="src"` in more than one place. Each `id` value must be unique across the whole document.

Comment: Do the links serve any purpose with javascript disabled? Might be easier to create the links with the jQuery if that's the case

Comment: not sure why i added the id Chris. We can remove it. It was easier to do this using jquery Gareth. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098600/jquery-using-getjson-to-return-images-and-then-wrap-them-in-anchors  for what we came up with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script>
var div = window.document.getElementById("images");
var anchors = div.getElementsByTagName("A");
var imgs = div.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
for (var i = anchors.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    anchors[i].appendChild(imgs[i]);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

General strategy:

1. Get a reference to the "images" div
2. Create a temporary object to store images, e.g. `var imgs = {};`
3. Loop over all `img` elements within the div. For each element:

   - Add each element to `imgs`, using its `src` as the key
4. Loop over all `a` elements within the div. For each element:

   1. Lookup the image from `imgs` using the element's `href` attribute
   2. Remove the `img` from its current location, and re-insert it within the body of the `a`.

Comment: (assuming no particular ordering for images and/or links)